# Django - Ajax form fails while sending data

Tags: django, jquery

I am tryin to set my form button to save form without reload page.

everything looks correctly ; but i guess i am missing something. here are my codes:

**ajax part:**

```
$('#submit').click(function() {

        var title = $('#id_title').val();
        var body = $('#id_body').val();
        var isdraft = $('#id_isdraft').is(':checked');

        var ajaxOptions = {
            type: 'post',
            url: '/admin/post/save/',
            data: {
                'title': title,
                'body': body,
                'isdraft': isdraft
            },
            success: function(){
                alert("save success");
             },
            error: function(){
                alert("fail");
             }
           };

        $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
});
```

**views part:**

```
@require_POST
def save_post(request):
     title = request.POST['title']
     body = request.POST['body']
     isdraft = request.POST['isdraft']
     owner = request.user 

     post = Post(title=title, body=body, isdraft=isdraft, owner=owner)
     post.save()

     return HttpResponse(200)
```

**url part:**

```
url(r'^admin/post/save/', view='save_post', name='save_post'),
```

when i click submit button ; ajax error function called.

thank you

edit:

on firefox ; it saves data into db. it shows error but saves again.

but in console [runserver lines] ; there is a error:

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('10.10.10.1', 42526)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 560, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 322, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/opt/sosyate_/sosyate_env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 139, in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 618, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 661, in finish
    self.wfile.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 297, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(buffer(data, write_offset, buffer_size))
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

but in chrome ; there is no error like this. it just throw the error that i defined under ajax function.

Comment: please fix the formatting in your views file. In `views.save_post()` what is `Post`? Try using your browsers developer tools to see what the response is to the ajax call - this may contain more information.

Comment: i am not sure ; but it throws 403 error.

Comment: not sure about what? 403 is Access Forbidden - you are seeing that where?

Comment: Don't forgot the [CSRF on ajax](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the decorator not working well with the ajax request. I would suggest removing it and placing the check inside the method

```
def save_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
         title = request.POST['title']
         body = request.POST['body']
         isdraft = request.POST['isdraft']
         owner = request.user 

         post = Post(title=title, body=body, isdraft=isdraft, owner=owner)
         post.save()

         return HttpResponse(200)
```